# What algorithm is used in Scheme for pattern matching in syntax-case?

Tags: scheme

R. Kent Dybvig in his [Writing Hygienic Macros in Scheme with Syntax-Case](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/%7Edyb/pubs/tr356.pdf) paper (p. 9) uses this example to illustrate Scheme's pattern matching:

```lisp
(define-syntax let1
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
     ((((i v) ...) e1 e2 ...)
      (syntax ((lambda (i ...) e1 e2 ...) v ...))))))
```

I'm curious, what is the algorithm used for matching it? I am aware of the existence of different pattern matching algorithms, but here it seems that the algorithm needs to be something very simple given the very restricted nature of the patterns (unique identifiers, very simple grammar), but I was not able to find any references describing it in greater detail.

In the example above `e1 e2 ...` is quite simple, since it can be matched as-is or by the subpattern `e2 ...` alone (?). The part `((i v) ...)` is more tricky as it doesn't match directly `i ...` nor `v ...`, so here it can either do some more complex matching or just considers it as "the other ellipsis".

- What exactly is the algorithm?
- Where I could find more information on it?

Comment: The two occurrences of `i` in the example are connected by the _expander algorithm_, of which
pattern matching is only a small part.
`(i v)` is part of the _pattern_ (which can match input), `(i ...)` is part of the _template_.
The expander is described briefly in Section 4 of the referenced paper, and more fully in
[Syntactic Abstraction: The syntax-case expander](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/bc-syntax-case.pdf) [Dybvig 2007]

Comment: @mnemenaut  in the unification algorithm, the fact that `i` is duplicated, means that no fresh variable is generated.  But I think he completely lacks understanding of unification first.  He should start reading a basic book of logic before to try understanding this, I already answered him so, and he was not content with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer in the papers [Writing Macros in Continuation-Passing Style](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.5638) by Erik Hilsdale and Daniel P. Friedman, [Macro-by-Example](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/ftp/techreports/TR206.pdf) by Eugene E. Kohlbecker and Mitchell Wand, and [Syntactic Abstraction: The syntax-case expander](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/%7Edyb/pubs/bc-syntax-case.pdf) by R. Kent Dybvig.

My mistake was misunderstanding the meaning of the `...`. I assumed it is a wildcard for "anything that follows", while in fact `e2 ...` and `(i v) ...` should be read as "PATTERN and the following elements alike". In such a case `e1 e2 ...` matches the series of one or more `e[j]` objects, while `(i v) ...` matches a series of `(i v)[j]` pairs so that the elements can be extracted individually like `i[j]...` and `v[j]...` if we abuse the notation and add indexes in the square brackets.

So indeed the matching algorithm is rather simple: it matches the literals as-is, matches objects with keywords, matches the structures creating subpatterns (lists), but also has `...` for "the last pattern can be repeated". As noticed by mnemenaut in the comment (+1), the more complicated and interesting part is rather expanding the templates with the pattern, as described in the mentioned papers.

Comment: I think `p ...` matches a sequence of 0 or more objects, each matching the pattern `p`.

Comment: @WillNess yes, correct.

Comment: This means `e1 e2 ...` matches the sequence of 1 or more objects. Maybe make it clearer in the answer?...